# DMOZ shutting down

Tags: discussion

Per an announcement on the home page, DMOZ (The Open Directory Project) is shutting down permanently on March 14, 2017.

Many, if not all, of the questions tagged [dmoz](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dmoz) are now stale and should probably be closed.

Comment: I'd be in favor of closing unanswered dmoz questions to get them off the list of unanswered questions.   What is the use case for closing the others?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller: I'd expect that questions with answers have solutions that no longer work/are not valid. And, really, no other answers can be added except "you can't; DMOZ closed". If a question can no longer be answered, is there a reason to leave it open?

Comment: Aside: There is a Facebook group for DMOZ editor alumni.   If you were a DMOZ editor you can request to join.  https://www.facebook.com/groups/1722149908115641/

Comment: If the answers are no longer relevant, it might be better to "lock" them rather than close them.   That would preserve them in their current state.  I believe that we can also add a message to locked questions.

Comment: Whatever works for you. I just thought it'd be better to let the community know about it rather than adding a duplicate "DMOZ shut down" answer to all of the questions. (Admittedly, there aren't many.)

Comment: It is a good suggestion, thank you for bringing it up here.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I think locking them is appropriate. Along with closing unanswered ones. From an historical perspective, the answered onews probably ought to be retained. There may not be many of them, this time, so the work may not be extensive. Later, however, when some similar issue arises, there may be a larger collection to deal with. The action taken here could set a precedent for the site. How the questions are handled could also impact Google rankings. That should also be evaluated if so.

Answer (score 6):

There appears to be only 17 questions containing [DMOZ](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=dmoz+is%3Aq) as a search term on the site, and 9 questions with the [DMOZ tag](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dmoz).

The OP answered one of these questions titled [Is DMOZ still 'active'?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/18494/is-dmoz-still-active) with the information about the announcement that DMOZ was closing. The [About](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/tags/dmoz/info) section of the DMOZ tag had also been updated to reflect this announcement.

There are questions like [How can I add my website to DMOZ?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/67558/how-can-i-add-my-website-to-dmoz) that visitors might still find in the future. We should lock those to prevent useless/spam answers, but also include a link to the above question "Is DMOZ still 'active'?" so that users can view the history of answers there, and once it does close, that can be updated and then also locked.

Any future questions related to DMOZ can then be closed with an explanation linking to "Is DMOZ still 'active'?" so that additional questions do not get added to the site, since they'll automatically be removed after 30 days.

That way we can maintain the historical perspective that Gypsy Spellweaver suggested, with a time-line related to DMOZ's closing attached to them.

Lastly, I suggest that we convert [Is DMOZ still 'active'?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/18494/is-dmoz-still-active) to a [community wiki](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki) catch-all question.

Comment: Once again, @dan is the man with a plan! Cheers!!